# Window Media Player Current position issue

Tags: c#, .net, media, windows-media-player

I am using Windows Media Player in my desktop application. I set a value in my application which I then provide to Window Media Player's Current Position property like this:

```
 wMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = Convert.ToDouble(StartTimeofVideo);
```

Now the problem I am facing is that some times it start from accurate position but when I change the value let's say from 140 seconds to 144 seconds it does not play from 144 seconds it plays from 140 or 139 seconds.

It must be some thing simple I am missing but I have not find any solution for it.

Comment: Your code looks like the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd564740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So the question is what are the values of StartTimeofVideo and currentPosition, before and after you change the values.

Comment: Let me elaborate more. I have button when I click on it, the variable StartTimeofVideo is set. Before its value is zero. The current position of the media player is also zero before setting it with StartTimeofVideo. After setting it the value of current position is same as of StartTimeofVideo.